# How can I safely clean a bird's cage indoors?

Tags: birds, cleaning

When I adopted my conure, I was given her old cage. My conure is at least 15, and presumably she's lived in this cage for her whole life, so it's a bit dirty. When she first arrived, I rubbed the whole cage down with plain water, and that helped a bit, but I'd like something more heavy duty.

What products can I use to thoroughly clean my bird's cage? I would prefer things that are commonly found in a household.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Safe Products

[Dawn dish soap](https://dawn-dish.com/en-us/dawn-saves-wildlife) (antibacterial) or 3 parts water to 1 part vinegar.

### The Process

I soak cages for about 5-10 minutes in a tub full of **hot** water and cleaning solution, this allows any hard feces to easily wash off with a cloth. Once washed I spray [Natures Miracle Bird Cage Cleaner](http://www.naturesmiracle.com/products/other-pets/bird-cage-cleaners/bird-cage-cleaner-and-deodorizer.aspx) (deodorizer) and let sit for 5 minutes before doing a final rinse, once rinsed I dry it off with a towel.

I highly recommend Natures Miracle, I started using this product a few months ago and it does **WONDERS** eliminating smell (not masking).

- Cage liners should be changed daily.
- Base of cages should be washed once a week and the bars wiped down.
- Cage should be disassembled and fully washed once a month.

Comment: Would Nature's Miracle be safe to use if my bird is still in/around the cage? I can't reliably take her out just yet, and I'd like to avoid forcing her out.

Comment: I would not use it with the bird still in the cage, they recommend to take toys, food, water and the bird out of the cage before using. You can wait for her to leave her cage by herself and then begin the cleaning process, if you have java trees or play stand near her cage for her to fly to that would help.

Comment: She can't leave the cage by herself is the issue - her previous owners had her wings severely clipped & she's just starting to molt. I will hold off on using this product then and stick to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.... So I know there are a few household cleaners that are safe, but off the top of my head I can't think of them BUT most you still have to use water to rinse off. Are you wanting something to clean the cage and keep the bird in it while you do so?

Although citrus fruits are not recommended for birds to eat regularly, small amounts are not poisonous, and many seed diets add orange oil for flavor, scent and as an acidic preservative. BUT besides that, you can used lemons, oranges and limes to clean the cage. It's acidic enough that it breaks down goopies, and leaves a fresh scent AND if your bird chews on metal or plastic that has the fruit juice dried on it, it's safe.

I'd say slice up lemons into wedges, pull out the seeds and scrub away; you'll make a drippy mess, but it's an edible drippy mess vs any chemical sprays that would drip too.

You can try it out n let us know how it goes.....

There are also bird poop cleaners safe for birds, that are not household items if all else fails. Ex.Poop Off and the Bird Cage Cleaner made by Nature's Miracle

Comment: Lemon seems like a great suggestion! I can't reliably take her out of her cage yet (her prev owners let her get a bit cage aggressive), so she would likely be in/around her cage while cleaning. Also I think I may just get Poop Off anyway bc everyone seems to recommend it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Poop off has a few different sized bottles, a spray bottle, large refill bottle and one that  comes with a scrub brush head ON the bottle. It also comes in a wipe dispenser version, similar to Lysol disinfecting wipes, and would assume that style dries the quickest, but have only tried with scrub brush. I no longer use Poop Off, but was very happy with results when I did use it.

Answer (score 0):

Vinegar and water is a very good idea. I've used it for almost all types of household cleaning and it's safe for animals. It's also really cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Poop-Off Bird Poop Remover. I do use the premoistened wipes while my birds and hamster are in their cages. The smell is pleasant and the animals don't mind it at all.